# plpgsql function incurs huge performance overhead

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following fairly simple query in a Report using Postgres 9.3 in the DB back-end:

```
SELECT * FROM source
JOIN sourcelevel USING (source_id)
JOIN level USING (level_id)
WHERE
  CASE WHEN isReportAdmin(1) THEN true
  ELSE source_id in (SELECT source_id FROM sourceemployee WHERE employee = 1)
  END
```

I'm very new to SQL optimization, and I'm trying to understand the following behaviour:

At the moment the `isReportAdmin` function simply returns 'true'

```
create or replace function isReportAdmin(employee_id integer) RETURNS bool AS $$
        BEGIN
                RETURN 't';
        END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When I run the report query, it takes approximately two minutes to execute.

If I replace the function call with simply: `CASE WHEN true THEN...`

it takes two seconds to return.

Could you explain in intermediate terms, why would the function call incur so much overhead?  Is there a common strategy for dealing with this kind of function in a query?

Comment: User-defined functions have very nasty effects on query optimization.  You need to look at the execution plans to understand the difference in performance.

Comment: Also, the function is not marked as immutable or stable, so it defaults to volatile, meaning it has to run that function for every row.  If it were marked immutable, it would run it once and the performance would likely be similar to hardcoding the value.  Just be careful and don't mark a function as immutable if it's not actually immutable.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, PL/pgSQL does incur a [performance overhead](https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/stored-functions/). You can remove that overhead in most cases by defining your function as `language sql`:

```
create or replace function isreportadmin(employee_id integer) 
  RETURNS bool 
AS $$
  select true;
$$ 
LANGUAGE sql
stable;
```

If it is defined as `stable` Postgres is very often able to [inline](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Inlining_of_SQL_functions) the (SQL) function and get rid of the overhead completely.

---

Most probably your actual function does some lookup in the database. You can still keep that as a SQL function. If you e.g. have a table named `user_roles` where you need to do the lookup for the passed employee_id, you could use something like this:

```
create or replace function isreportadmin(p_employee_id integer) 
  RETURNS bool 
AS $$
  select exists (select *
                 from user_roles ur
                 where ur.employee_id = p_employee_id 
                   and ur.is_admin);
$$ 
LANGUAGE sql
stable;
```

Comment: it seems to be inlining the function with that change - amazing.  thanks